# How to find first minimum after first peak in array?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I am trying to find the first minimum after the first peak in a data array. Here is my code:

```
x = array

mins = argrelextrema(x, np.less)[0]
mins_above_zero = np.where(x[mins] > 0)[0]
ag = x[mins[mins_above_zero]].argmin()
true_minimum_index = mins[ag]

pyplot.scatter(mins, x[mins])
pyplot.plot(x)
pyplot.ylim(0, 2000)
```

It currently picks out too many minimums.

If I have a numpy array like this:

```
array([  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   1.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   1.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   2.,   0.,   2.,   1.,   3.,
         1.,   2.,   5.,   8.,   6.,  55., 396., 608., 157.,  40.,  45.,
        43.,  51.,  74.,  89., 107., 121.,  98., 111., 122., 170., 187.,
       190., 229., 284., 372., 450., 457., 327., 328., 318., 288., 290.,
       262., 235., 223., 177., 232., 217., 234., 261., 206., 192., 221.,
       189., 181., 185., 162., 140., 144., 171., 176., 168., 213., 222.,
       314., 397., 413., 429., 442., 352., 416., 439., 424., 480., 479.,
       515., 522., 569., 543., 626., 666., 637., 680., 678., 747., 720.,
       695., 674., 605., 490., 475., 332., 284., 252., 169., 140., 117.,
        86.,  71.,  58.,  55.,  37.,  45.,  35.,  25.,  21.,  16.,  14.,
        17.,  12.,   9.,   7.,   6.,   0.,   6.,   6.,   6.,   3.,   1.,
         1.,   4.,   2.,   1.,   4.,   0.,   2.,   2.,   0.,   1.,   2.,
         0.,   0.,   4.,   0.,   1.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   1.,   1.,   0.])
```

That creates a plot like this except just with the minimum after the first peak:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try playing with the order of `argrelextrema`

With your array data:

```
x = array

# Order 2 looks at more than just the immediate numbers around a variable
mins = argrelextrema(x, np.less, order=2)[0]
print(mins)
mins_above_zero = np.where(x[mins] > 0)[0]
ag = x[mins[mins_above_zero]].argmin()
true_minimum_index = mins[ag]

#Grabs the first relative minimum
mins = mins[0]

pyplot.scatter(mins, x[mins])
pyplot.plot(x)
pyplot.ylim(0, 2000)
```

Which creates:

[image]